# Screen refresh in Tableview after call to DetailView Controoler

Tags: ios, xcode

I am excuting the following line to add a Detail Viwe after my Table View is loaded:

```
if (!self.addView) {
        self.addView = [[AddView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddView" bundle:nil];
    }
          [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.addView animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"I am done, now what");
```

Then I am presented with a screen of text boxes... I enter data and I save to a plist...
then to return Programatically, i perform the following line:

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

My question is how to I refresh the tableview with the new record? I know it is in viewWillAppear method [self.tableview reloadData], but how do I trigger the viewWillAppear, as it is not gettin to that method after return? 
any help would be appreciated.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run reloadData every time your tableView is about to appear you can run [self.tableview reloadData] in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Here is an explanation from Apple's view controller programming guide: [link]http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH12-SW2[/link]

Comment: i am sorry it is in the viewWillAppear method, but it is not going there.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying you are running [self.tableview reloadData] in viewWillAppear, but the table view doesn't seem to be reloading, correct? Are you sure the data source for your table view is up to date with your newly created item by the time reloadData runs? You mentioned you save your data to a plist file. Do you read this plist file and store your data in an NSMutableArray or some other collection? If so, are you rereading the plist file and updating this collection before running reloadData?

Comment: Well, Alex on inital load of the data, in viewDidLoad I load the data from the pist. Where do code to re-read the data and how do I force the viewWillAppear (i put NSLog in the viewWillAppear and the code is never executed.

Comment: Hi Paul, I see you have another thread going with your viewWillAppear issue. I think once that is sorted out you will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to put the `[self.tableView reloadData]` in the `viewWillAppear` method instead of the `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: thank you... I actually did, I typed incorrectly. Thank you though